# Why do I need a HAL Delay before using HAL I2C Master Recive IT?

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal, motordriver

I am currently working on a project using the TLE493 HAL sensors.
As controller, I use the STM32F303CT.

Now here comes the confusion when I use the ST HAL Libraries:

```c
while(!SENSOR_OK) {

        HAL_Delay(5);
        ret =  HAL_I2C_Master_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, TLE493_ADDR, rbuffer, sizeof(rbuffer));
        // some more configuration
```

When I use a HAL_Delay 5ms, the I2C communication with the sensor works properly. Without it, I get HAL_BUSY as return value of the HAL I2C function.

Do I miss some point here or is the HAL library kinda messed up?

Btw: I am using the ST Motor Control workbench as well on this controller. Maybe this disturbs my function in any way.

Thank you for your answers

Cheers

Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why the I2C needs the delay. Setup time by the chip or the I2C controller come to my mind for example.

The HAL Library offers the function HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady to check if the device is ready for communication, you should probably look into that function.

Best regards
Dariusz

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I will check out this function and let you know if it helps.

Cheers Jimmy